# Controlling smoke/fire emision amount

Tags: smoke-simulation

It is possible to animate the emission of the smoke in smoke sim? I tried to insert keyframes in the fuelAmmount propierty in the flow object but it didn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the settings, I couldn't find the fuelAmmount property.

Comment: @stacker I think the OP means *Flame Rate* (it's called `fuel_amount` in the api) However, keyframing it works fine for me..

Comment: And using a pure fire emitter, do you think it is a bug?

Answer (score 7):

Controlling the amount of fire by keyframing the *Flame Rate* works for me:

[image]

However it doesn't affect the smoke.

To affect the smoke as well, you could try animating the *Volume Factor*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just came on this answer today as I was also looking to animate my smoke/fire animation and although gandalf3 gave me a direction to go in I found that if you set the Surf(Surface) property of the Flow Source to 0 at the start of the animation and keyframe it and than set it to a larger value, i.e. 1, at a second frame and keyframe it and than return the value to 0 at a third keyframe the smoke and fire will turn on at your beginning frame and off at the last frame.
Example: Set your Surface property value to 0 at frame 1 and insert a keyframe in the Surf property box and than advance the Current frame value to 10 and adjust the Surf property value to 1 and insert a keyframe in the Surf property box and than advance your Current frame value to 20 and set the Surf property to 0 and insert a keyframe.  This eliminates the need to adjust two properties, instead only adjusting one.  As I am new to this forum I have yet to be able to upload video as gandalf3 has above so I am hoping there is not a problem with me just pointing to gandalf3s video above to have those interested in this technique see the Surf property that I speak of, which is located just above the Vol property(Volume Factor) he mentions.  Hope this adds to the solution appropriately.  Happy Blending all.