# Keyframing start and end of smoke simulation

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation

Can anyone help me with quick smoke?
I am still very new to blender and I am confused on how I can key frame quick smoke to start at a certain frame with the explosion I have set up.

Comment: As far as i know, smoke simulations do not require keyframes. Watch this video for explosions. http://video.search.yahoo.com/video/play;_ylt=A2KLqIHFlUJUfTMAUAP7w8QF;_ylu=X3oDMTB2ZjRyaHJ1BHNlYwNzcgRzbGsDdmlkBHZ0aWQDVjE4MARncG9zAzI-?p=youtube+explosion+blender&vid=fe7633565ff6e91b9b5fa551f7056e8f&l=38%3A32&turl=http%3A%2F%2Fts2.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DVN.608030798067600613%26pid%3D15.1&rurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DmtSbZtPO_2w&tit=How+to+Create+an+%3Cb%3EExplosion+%3C%2Fb%3Ein+%3Cb%3EBlender%3C%2Fb%3E&c=1&sigr=11a1ecb2a&sigt=11jjiag8a&age=0&vm=r&tt=b

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7409/599

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the mesh as the flow source,  then animate the *Density* of the *Flow* object.
[image: smoke density field]
Hover over the field and press <kbd>I</kbd> to add a keyframe. Or <kbd>RMB [image: RMB]</kbd> on the field and choose *Insert Keyframe*.

If you are using a emitter particle system, then use the start and end time of the particle system.

Comment: When keyframing the Density, will the simulation appear as if it started at the frame you keyframed it? Will you need to bake the frames before it?