# Flickering Fire in shape of mesh/object

Tags: particles, physics, smoke-simulation

I have a 2D vector image that I converted into a mesh with some thickness in blender. Is there a way to animate fire that flickers in the shape of that mesh? I'm basically trying to create something like this, just in a different shape. [image: flickering fire treble clef]
Ive tried different smoke/fire tutorials, but the I can't get the fire to not expand and rise. I need it to just flicker at that size and volume.

Comment: hi, have you also seen tutorials like this one? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChUkVRD_UzM (just one of many found with a simple search) or, try to share your current setup, and results, so that people can comment and correct those...

Comment: anyway, controlling the "flame rate" value of the emitting object (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/smoke/types/flow_object.html) seems the best option, see also this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7409/controlling-smoke-fire-emision-amount

Comment: Thank you for the resources! I'll check them out and see what I can do.